# Pyinstaller failed to build wxpython app with error wx._xml missing

Tags: python, windows, compiler-errors, wxpython, executable

I tried to build my wxpython app with Pyinstaller, it built ok but when run, an exception occurred with message:

```
  File "wx_gui.py", line 11, in <module>
    import wx.xrc
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\wx\xrc.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 573, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: No module named 'wx._xml'
Failed to execute script ir2_main
```

I checked in the site-packages folder and there was no wx._xml.pyd like there was wx._xrc.pyd. Could this be the reason and how can I fix it ?

Comment: You should state the versions of OS and wx you are using?

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to use Python 3.4 therefore you can only use wxPython Phoenix.

Looking into the last [snapshot build](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/) wheel from end of October 2016 there is actually a `_xml.pyd` there, so maybe you have a bonkers wxPython installation?